# Can I Use Published Work for an MFA Writing Sample?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

This could be a no brainer of a question, but I thought I'd throw it out there to be safe. I'm applying to an American MFA program in Creative Writing and want to submit some of my best work for writing samples. Would there be a problem if I submitted writing that was published? I've found conflicting thought in my personal research, and none pertaining to my field.

Comment: If it is your writing then most likely yes. You can always ask them to be clear. Seems to me (but I’m in STEM) that showing you are an already published writer would be great.

Comment: Ask the program. I agree that this sounds like a no-brainer, but we here can't tell you what the policy at the program is. (They might have qualms about any potential editing your writing may have gone through, for instance.)

Comment: Ask the program